# Docker: Alias command name to run another sibling docker container

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I know how to -v the docker socket into a container to make the host's docker daemon available inside a container. Fine.

I have a dockerized application A that can operate on files on the host.

I have another dockerized application B that wants to use that application A to operate on files on the host, but is hardcoded to call `/usr/bin/A filename`.

How do I alias `/usr/bin/A` within container B, so that it will call out to the other container, like

`docker run -ti --rm A filename`

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, specially "that wants to use that application A to operate on files on the host, but is hardcoded to call /usr/bin/A filename"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just replace `/usr/bin/A` in container B with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
docker run -ti --rm A "$@"
```

You could do this in the image itself (via your `Dockerfile`), or you could bin-mount the script when you start container B (`docker run -v /path/to/my/script:/usr/bin/A ...`).

Now you run `/usr/bin/A some_filename` and it should do the right thing, assuming that you can successfully run `docker` inside the container.

Comment: That was painfully obvious in retrospect, thank you.